# OpenTok Android Signaling Tutorial - Session Error Domain

Tags: android, opentok, tokbox

I am using the text chat [tutorial](https://github.com/opentok/opentok-android-sdk-samples/tree/master/Signaling) from TokBox, but I'm encountering the following error(s) after I send the message (signal):

```
com.tokbox.android.tutorials.signaling E/MainActivity: Error Domain: SessionErrorDomain
Error Code: Session Disconnected
```

Please note that I'm currently hardcoding the session credentials.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. You must provide the code that generates this error. Please [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and also read [https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

TokBox Developer Evangelist here.

Based on your statement and the error you shared, it looks you are trying to send a signal, but you are not connected to an OpenTok [session](https://tokbox.com/developer/sdks/android/reference/com/opentok/android/Session.html).

Please make sure that you have successfully connected to an OpenTok session before you send a signal. To do so, make sure you that you have received the [`onConnected`](https://tokbox.com/developer/sdks/android/reference/com/opentok/android/Session.SessionListener.html#onConnected-com.opentok.android.Session-) event.

I recommend checking out the [step by step tutorial](https://tokbox.com/developer/tutorials/android/text-chat/) to learn more about creating a text chat application using the [OpenTok Android SDK](https://tokbox.com/developer/sdks/android/).